# get pc time with javascript and pass it using form

Tags: javascript, php

I have 2 php pages. In my first page I was trying to get pc's time with javascript. Then with the use of the form I want to pass in second php page and then to store it in my database. The problem is that I cannot pass pc's time on my form. Any idea what the problem is ?

This is my 1st page:

```
<?php

// get pc's time

$a='<script language="javascript">
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if(dd<10) {
dd="0"+dd
} 

if(mm<10) {
mm="0"+mm
} 

today = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes()+":" + today.getSeconds();
document.write(today);
</script>';

?>

<form>
<input id="today" name="today">
<input type="submit" value=" " >
</form>
```

Comment: you mean the second php that gets form data and store it in database?

Comment: It would appear that your javascript isn't running.

Comment: `document.write` outputs at the point it's called. So your generated date string is NOT being output in your form.

Comment: Are you echoing somewhere the $a variable holding the JS code?

Comment: I echo"$a"; and it is giving me the time. The only problem is that I cannot pass it in my form. I dont' have hidden the type in form in order to see what happens. It pass me nothing. If i change my form to  <input id="today" name="today" value="<?php echo"$a" ?>"> it pass into field the text <javascript>... etc and not the value of $a

Comment: how can it be possible by echo $a to give me the time, and when echo it inside form's value not to echo it?

Answer (score 0):

That looks a bit awkward to me, I don't think you can pass javascript variables in PHP, though I could be wrong

why don't you just use the date function in PHP.

Comment: lol, I don't have enough points yet to make a legit comment :-(

Answer (score 0):

You'd need something like this:

```
<form ... id="form">
   <input type="hidden" name="date" id="datefield">
</form>

<script>
   ... get your date/time value
   document.getElementById('datefield').value = your_date_string;
   document.getElementById('form').submit();
</script>
```

generate your date string, insert it into the form, then submit the form.

Comment: can you please write the javascript how it should be, because I cannot understand how to change it

Comment: We are not coders for hire, nor here to teach you how to write code. YOU need to write the JS. we'll try help fix it later on.